# Select Parent and Child if child has records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: firearms_firearmbook, inventory_inventory and inventory_inventorytransaction.

And i have 2 Cases:

> 1. If inventory_inventory Table has no inventory_inventorytransaction with item action of 16, show inventory_inventory record
> 2. If inventory_inventory Table has inventory_inventorytransaction with item action of 16, show inventory_inventory and inventory_inventorytransaction.item_action_id

The query bellow works for the first cause, but its not working for the second cause.
It should show smth like this:

```
-----------------------------------
| id    |    serial   | action_id |
-----------------------------------
   1         MAGUM        
   2         EAGLE          
   2         EAGLE         16
```

Query:

```
SELECT FB.id, INV.serial_number, INV.id, INVT.item_action_id FROM firearms_firearmbook AS FB
LEFT JOIN inventory_inventory AS INV ON INV.id = FB.item_id
LEFT JOIN inventory_inventorytransaction AS INVT ON INVT.item_id = INV.id AND INVT.item_action_id = 16
WHERE FB.store_id = 1
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff totally missclicked mysql, thanks :)

Comment: I don't see the requirement for producing the second record in the desired output.

Comment: @trincot i need it, cause they want to see every change that is made to that Item, plus the item itself. if the item has no changes it counts as 1, if item has a change, than it counts as 2

Comment: with "has a change", you mean "has a record with action 16"?

Comment: @trincot yes i mean has an record with action 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if there is an action 16 record for a given item, you need two records in the output: one with a blank in the third column, and one with 16 in the third column.

In that case you could do this:

```
with base as (
        select      fb.id, 
                    inv.serial_number, 
                    inv.id, 
        from        firearms_firearmbook as fb
        inner join  inventory_inventory as inv 
                on  inv.id = fb.item_id
        where       fb.store_id = 1
    )
select      base.*,
            invt.item_action_id 
from        base
inner join  inventory_inventorytransaction as invt 
        on  invt.item_id = base.id 
        and invt.item_action_id = 16
union all
select      base.*, 
            null 
from        base
order by    1, 2, 3, 4 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this is what your after.

I've made a CASE statement for the two situation you describe. I wasn't sure what you column you wanted for 2) when you say "inventory_inventory" so I put the id column and you can change it for another column.

I've also removed INVT.item_action_id = 16 part of the inventory_inventorytransaction join as I don't think it's necessary as it is handled in the CASE statement.

```
SELECT 
FB.id, 
INV.serial_number, 
INV.id, 
INVT.item_action_id, 
CASE 
  WHEN INVT.item_action_id = 16 THEN CAST(INV.id as VARCHAR)  + ' ' + CAST(INVT.item_action_id as VARCHAR) -- This is Case 2
  ELSE INV.record -- This is Case 1
END as answer
FROM firearms_firearmbook AS FB
LEFT JOIN inventory_inventory AS INV ON INV.id = FB.item_id
LEFT JOIN inventory_inventorytransaction AS INVT ON INVT.item_id = INV.id -- Removed JOIN on INVT.item_action_id = 16 and moved it to CASE
WHERE FB.store_id = 1;
```